# code compare two lists duplicated data and copy to another list

Tags: excel, vba

i would  help me about  my code  it compares  from sheet1 two columns a,b   and  the duplicated transfer to  sheet2  the  column c

```
     Sub COPY1()
Dim i
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Sheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value Then
  Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B1:B" & i), Sheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "A"))
        If Count > 1 Then
        Sheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "A").COPY Destination:=Sheets("sheet2").Range("B" & 
    Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End If
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Good news! your posted code works for me!  What is your problem.

Comment: it seems working  but  there is no data in sheet2  and  no error  it's strange

Comment: Your code transfers only if the match is **side-by-side**, that is if the duplicates are in the **same row**

Comment: here two columns are duplicated data it should transfer to a new column in sheet2 any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub COPY1()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With Sheets("sheet1")
        LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LastRow
            v = .Cells(i, "A").Value
                For j = 2 To LastRow
                    If v = .Cells(j, "B").Value Then
                        .Cells(i, "A").Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet2").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                    End If
                Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks  so  much   GARY  for  your answering  the  code is  perfect